# filtering Excel spreadsheet before exporting its data

Tags: microsoft-excel, export

I'm being sent many spreadsheets which contain data that needs to be imported into a database, but many of these sheets contain rows with values missing in a certain column.

Ideally these "malformed" rows would be excluded from the export (rather than removed afterwards from the database). Is there a way either to filter before export, or to populate a second sheet using something like this statement?

```
SELECT * FROM sheet1 WHERE [sheet1.column-reference] IS NOT NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have ms access, you can simply map sheet as external table or create view with xls sheet as source table

```
SELECT * FROM [Excel 8.0;HDR=Yes; Database=C:\Folder\Workbook.xls;].[SheetName]
```

If you have many sheet you can do this by vba script, but this is programming task.